# Can't run jupyter lab kernel after installation

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am not able to run Jupyter lab kernel and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

This is the error message

````
[E 2022-02-22 19:51:11.590 ServerApp] Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: 1ce0939d-da79-420d-bf36-86145176a54e)
[W 2022-02-22 19:51:11.602 ServerApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/1ce0939d-da79-420d-bf36-86145176a54e/channels?session_id=c740474d-d4e2-40a6-9dca-bad5e580a050 (::1): Kernel does not exist: 1ce0939d-da79-420d-bf36-86145176a54e ``` 



jupyter core     : 4.7.1
jupyter-notebook : 6.4.8
qtconsole        : 5.0.3
ipython          : 5.5.0
ipykernel        : 4.6.1
jupyter client   : 6.1.12
jupyter lab      : 3.0.14
nbconvert        : 6.0.7
ipywidgets       : 7.6.3
nbformat         : 5.1.3
traitlets        : 5.0.5
````